How to update or replace the service at run time which was registered/resolved using Module
We are using Autofac container for DI and registered/resolved our TableclientSerivce using Module.
But we have a scenario where this service (configuration) needs to be updated at runtime based on condition.
Ask: is there a way to update/replace the already registered/resolved service/component in autofac Module at run time from the code implementation?
Thank you,
Siva
Actually we are trying to connect to Azure storage table via TAbleservice client which holds endpoint configuration while registering in the module.
Based on the scenario the endpoint will change at runtime and needs to be updated from the code impplementation.

You can't change what's in a container once it's built. You have to rebuild the container if you need to change things.
That said, you can create a new lifetime scope and register things as part of that. This allows you to override - for that scope - registrations from the root container. This may allow your app to use a child lifetime scope as its "root container" instead of actually using the container directly and then if the registrations change you can drop the app lifetime scope and re-create a new one.

Thank you Travis for the prompt response and suggestions.
